# Have any Marxists won the Nobel Prize in the last 50 years?

Tags: political-theory, communism, marxism, honors

Have any avowed Marxists recently won the Nobel Prize, or any other significant economic recognition award?

Answer (score 4):

Nobel Peace prize tends to go to people who identify with [hard left wing in general](http://www.discoverthenetworks.org/printgroupProfile.asp?grpid=6979), and VERY often are Marxist (and even more often take Marxist-friendly, anti-capitalist positions without admitting to being Marxist).

Quite reflective of this is the fact that Nobel Peace Prize committe is **headed** by Thorbjørn Jagland (former Vice-President of the Socialist International)

- 2014: BOTH [Malala Yousafzai](http://www.scottspiegel.com/2014/10/15/nobel-peace-prize-committee-still-lauding-frauds/) and [Kailash Satyarthi](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/10/11/world/asia/kailash-satyarthis-nobel-peace-prize-caps-decades-of-fighting-child-slavery-in-india.html?_r=0) are openly Marxist
- I'm gonna throw Obama in there just for kindling and fireworks. He clearly subscribed to Marxist ideas in his youth, and still promotes many policies whose philosophical underpinnings are Marxist (class struggle, "to each according to his needs", ect...) though he's less of an overt Marxist since his entry into official US politics.
- 1990: Michail Gorbachev (duh)
- 1989: The 14th [Dalai Lama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/14th_Dalai_Lama#Economics)
- 1980: Adolfo Pérez Esquivel
- 1973: [Le Duc Tho](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%AA_%C4%90%E1%BB%A9c_Th%E1%BB%8D) (duh)

Comment: I was thinking something more along an economic theory award rather than the Nobel PP. I.e., "[Sveriges Riksbank Prize in Economic Sciences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmund_Phelps) in Memory of Alfred Nobel, referred to, colloquially, as the Nobel Prize in Economics," but awarded to someone with a raging Marxist theory instead. Might be difficult since Marxism is dead.

Comment: "take Marxist-friendly, anti-capitalist positions without admitting to being Marxist" - that presupposes a rather black-and-white view of politics. If you're not pro-capitalist, you apparently have to be in the one other camp which is labeled Marxist.

Comment: I wouldn't consider the 14th Dalai Lama as identifying as a Marxist. In fact, he was quite disparaging about the communist chinese who took over Tibet as being not particularly sincere in their marxism and more interested in material advancement.